# what user or users are querying a postgres db table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to identify what users are querying a specific table in a Postgres db?  Looking to audit a table and who is querying it.

Comment: You can look at the pgAudit extension, that should do what you want.

Comment: thank you.  Now I need to confirm on whether or not this extension is installed / enabled on the AWS RDS instance we are using